# How can I transform repeated data from dataframe into single dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and I'm trying to get accustomed to it.

Basically, I have an excel file with student info and I read it into python using pandas. It looks something like this:

| _id | student_id | first_name | last_name | type | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | John | Doe | Project | 5.92 |
| 2 | 1001 | John | Doe | Oral | 2.34 |
| 3 | 1001 | John | Doe | Quiz | 6.59 |
| 4 | 1001 | John | Doe | Essay | 9.58 |
| 5 | 1002 | Harry | Schmoe | Project | 8.92 |
| 6 | 1002 | Harry | Schmoe | Oral | 5.94 |
| 7 | 1002 | Harry | Schmoe | Quiz | 4.75 |
| 8 | 1002 | Harry | Schmoe | Essay | 9.58 |

I want to transform it into a dictionary to look like this:

```json
[
 {
   '_id': 1,
   'student_id': 1001,
   'first_name': 'John',
   'last_name': 'Doe',
   'results': [
     {'type': 'Project', 'grade': 5.92}
     {'type': 'Oral', 'grade': 2.34}
     {'type': 'Quiz', 'grade': 6.59}
     {'type': 'Essay', 'grade': 9.58}
   ]
 },
 {
   '_id': 2,
   'student_id': 1002,
   'first_name': 'Harry',
   'last_name': 'Schmoe',
   'results': [
     {'type': 'Project', 'grade': 8.92}
     {'type': 'Oral', 'grade': 5.94}
     {'type': 'Quiz', 'grade': 4.75}
     {'type': 'Essay', 'grade': 9.58}
   ]
 }
]
```

This is what I've tried, but it does not work as intended

```python
grouped = df.groupby(['_id', 'student_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
transformed_data = []
for index, group in grouped:
    group_dict = {
        "_id": index[0],
        "student_id": index[1],
        "first_name": index[2],
        "last_name": index[3],
        "results": dict(zip(group['type'], group['grade']))
    }
    transformed_data.append(group_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to group only by `student_id` (that value is unique for each student):

```py
out = []
for _id, (_, g) in enumerate(df.groupby("student_id"), 1):
    d = g[["student_id", "first_name", "last_name"]].iloc[0]
    results = [dict(type=t, grade=g) for t, g in zip(g["type"], g["grade"])]
    out.append(
        {
            "_id": _id,
            **d.to_dict(),
            "results": results,
        }
    )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "student_id": 1001,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "results": [
            {"type": "Project", "grade": 5.92},
            {"type": "Oral", "grade": 2.34},
            {"type": "Quiz", "grade": 6.59},
            {"type": "Essay", "grade": 9.58},
        ],
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "student_id": 1002,
        "first_name": "Harry",
        "last_name": "Schmoe",
        "results": [
            {"type": "Project", "grade": 8.92},
            {"type": "Oral", "grade": 5.94},
            {"type": "Quiz", "grade": 4.75},
            {"type": "Essay", "grade": 9.58},
        ],
    },
]
```

Comment: not the most pythonic/easy to understand function, even if it does the job :).

Comment: That is a great and elegantly pythonic solution! +1

Comment: @PaulS id recommend you do an in depth chapter about manipulating data with pandas. The answer is clearly not pythonic, as commented on your post. It gets the job done, but has no reading ease even if youre a senior developer in python

Answer (score 0):

```
data["_id"] = data["student_id"].rank(method="dense")
data["results"] = data.apply(lambda x: [{"type": x["type"], "grade": x["grade"]}],axis=1)
grouped_data = data.groupby(["_id","student_id","first_name","last_name"],as_index=False)["results"].sum()
grouped_data.to_dict("records")

#
[{'_id': 1.0,
  'student_id': 1001,
  'first_name': 'John',
  'last_name': 'Doe',
  'results': [{'type': 'Project', 'grade': 5.92},
   {'type': 'Oral', 'grade': 2.34},
   {'type': 'Quiz', 'grade': 6.59},
   {'type': 'Essay', 'grade': 9.58}]},
 {'_id': 2.0,
  'student_id': 1002,
  'first_name': 'Harry',
  'last_name': 'Schmoe',
  'results': [{'type': 'Project', 'grade': 8.92},
   {'type': 'Oral', 'grade': 5.94},
   {'type': 'Quiz', 'grade': 4.75},
   {'type': 'Essay', 'grade': 9.58}]}]
```

Firstly we overwrite the `_id` with a ranking of the student_id using `dense` so that all similar ids will get the same value.

Then we create a results column containing a list of dictionary. That we will use for the group by with `sum` to append all lists into one big list containing all the data.

Then `to_dict("records")` to get the right output format

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which uses `groupby` to form groups per student and afterwards uses [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct the list of the wanted dictionaries:

```
g = df.groupby('student_id')

[{'_id': i+1,
  **x.iloc[:,1:4].to_dict(orient='records')[0],
  'results': x.iloc[:, 4:].to_dict(orient='records')}
 for i, (_, x) in enumerate(g)]
```

Output:

```
[{'_id': 1,
  'student_id': 1001,
  'first_name': 'John',
  'last_name': 'Doe',
  'results': [{'type': 'Project', 'grade': 5.92},
   {'type': 'Oral', 'grade': 2.34},
   {'type': 'Quiz', 'grade': 6.59},
   {'type': 'Essay', 'grade': 9.58}]},
 {'_id': 2,
  'student_id': 1002,
  'first_name': 'Harry',
  'last_name': 'Schmoe',
  'results': [{'type': 'Project', 'grade': 8.92},
   {'type': 'Oral', 'grade': 5.94},
   {'type': 'Quiz', 'grade': 4.75},
   {'type': 'Essay', 'grade': 9.58}]}]
```

Comment: I did, it creates more ambiguity than clarity. Code should be neat and understandable without having to run it line by line.

Comment: Also it is inspired by a different answer, so no clear added value to the OP